# how to display the list of buttons like drop down list for a button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uibutton, radiobuttonlist, uitoolbaritem

i am new to iPhone programming...
can any body help me out please...
in my app i am displaying an image, transparent html page with text about that image and there is audio instead of html text...
in the bottom tool bar i have button 'VIEW".. i want this button to show the 3 (radio or normal) buttons in a list like drop up list(for enable/disable the bgimage, audio, text)...
How to display the list of buttons when i click on VIEW button...

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone does not have a build in radio list. You need to implement your custom view to make one. You may try to inherit table view to create a selection list. And for the on / off part, you can try UISwitch.